# Displaying only first 100 chars of character object

Tags: r, object, character

I have a read in a corpus of text with the following command and assigned it to an object in R.  Now I would like to only display the first 100 characters of the character object.  How is this possible?

```
text <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size) 

> class(text)
[1] "character"

> nchar(text)
 [1] 32460
```

Comment: To just display it, see `?str` -- `str(text, nchar.max = 100)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `substr` ?

```
substr(text, 1, 100)
```

or even `substring`

```
substring(text, 1, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
substr(x, start, stop)
substring(text, first, last = 1000000L)
substr(x, start, stop) <- value
substring(text, first, last = 1000000L) <- value
```

use these for extracting or replacing  substrings in a character vector.